# connect to host mysql database from inside rstudio docker

Tags: mysql, r, docker

I have set up Rstudio as a container on a server using a Rocker image. My MySQL instance is not in a docker and is running on the host machine. The db is a production database - so to dockerise the db as well isn't an option.

Can I connect to the host MySQL from inside the docker container running RStudio? The RStudio container runs perfectly, its just when I try and connect to the 'outside' MySQL to write data to db that I get a problem.

Currently trying with `R` just hanging in the end:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
  db_user <- Sys.getenv("server_user")
  db_password <- Sys.getenv("server_pass")
  db_host <- '172.17.0.1' # docker ip
  db_dbname <- "test"

  mydb <-
    dbConnect(
      MySQL(),
      user = db_user,
      password = db_password,
      dbname = db_dbname,
      host = db_host, 
      port = 3306
    )
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.1' (107)
```

**UPDATE, hack solution:**

Wanting to keep the container running with all the port mapping I ended up adding a rule to the iptables and connecting to the database as if I was connecting to it from another server:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp -s 172.17.0.2 --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "docker DB access"
```

I also created a special docker user in MySQL that can access database:

```
CREATE USER 'docker'@'172.17.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'XXX';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, CREATE ON *.* 'docker'@'172.17.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'XXX';
```

Although its a bit of a hack, I avoid all the problems that come with --net='host'

Comment: It's always necessary to show what error you get for others to try solving your problem. What happens when you start the container? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can run your image as `host` mode.

```
docker run --net="host" ...
```

If you use `host` mode, mean you can't listen the same port in your container, because that will cause `port already bind error`.

When you run your container as `host` mode, you can visit your Host's server. Here is MySQL with `127.0.0.1` instead of `172.17.0.1`.

Comment: This works, but is there any way to run network as host without the following occurring: `WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode`. I would like to run RStudio on a random port, say 8657:8787, instead of the default for security reasons. Also, I sometimes deploy apis through docker and then the mapping of ports become important for load-balancing

Comment: You can't map your listen port as normal, `-p 8657:8787` are not going to work, but you can listen any port by config it `-v my.conf:default.conf`.